# If value in column A can not be found in column B, remove row in R

Tags: regex, r

I am looking for a way to match one column to the other (but considering word boundaries). If there's no match, remove the whole row. An example: in the case that there is no exact token match (note `banana != bananas`) between NODE and SENTENCE (dataframe `df`), remove the row. In other words: `if (\b.+\b) in NODE can't be found in SENTENCE, remove the row`.

```
NODE     |     SENTENCE
-----------------------------------------------------------
banana         I am a banana and I like it
banana         We ate two bananas yesterday
banana         I ate a banana two days ago
coffee         Would you like a cup of coffee?
coffee         We went by that new coffeeshop the other day
```

Result

```
NODE     |     SENTENCE
-----------------------------------------------------------
banana         I am a banana and I like it
banana         I ate a banana two days ago
coffee         Would you like a cup of coffee?
```

I thought of using `ifelse`, but I'm not entirely sure how to apply this.

```
ifelse(df$NODE==df$SENTENCE,NA,???)
```

---

EDIT: considering nico's answer, this doesn't work for me. However, using `\\s` instead of `\\b` works. Doesn't `-` imply a word boundary? The down-side of this is that it won't detect when the node is at the beginning or end of a sentence (because it then isn't preceded or followed by a spatial character).:

```
r <- c("Het label heeft ook verantwoordelijkheidsgevoel: aan de lancering van B-Camp wordt een Goodwill Project gekoppeld, een fonds dat zijn financiële bijdrage wil leveren ter bestrijding van de aids-plaag.",
    "B-Camp koos voor de opvang en verzorging van kinderen besmet met het aids-virus.",
    "Hij zei dat hij aids had.",
    "Aids in het land?")
s <- c("aids","aids","aids","aids")
d1 <- data.frame(node = s,sentence=r)

matches <- mapply(grep, paste0("(?i)\\s", d1$node, "\\s"), d1$sentence)
to.keep <- sapply(matches, length)>0
(d1 <- d1[to.keep,])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
node    sentence
---------------------------------
aids    Hij zei dat hij aids had.
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
node    sentence
----------------
aids    Hij zei dat hij aids had.
aids    Aids in het land?
```

Comment: @BillWoodger Since there are only two columns and five rows I'm not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: Ah. I thought I, am, a, banana etc were all "columns". So you just need to know it the second contains the first, on the basis of words?

Comment: @BillWoodger NODE and SENTENCE are two columns in `df`. Yes. I need to keep the rows in which the sentence column contains exactly the node value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible vectorized solution using the `stringi` package (though possibly over-complicated...)

```
library(stringi)
indx <- as.logical(rowSums(with(df, 
                                NODE == stri_split_regex(SENTENCE,
                                "[[:punct:] ]", simplify = TRUE))))
df[indx, ]
#    NODE                        SENTENCE
# 1 banana     I am a banana and I like it
# 3 banana     I ate a banana two days ago
# 4 coffee Would you like a cup of coffee?
```

The idea here is to a convert `SENTENCE` to a matrix of words split by punctuation or a space and then simply find if there's an exact match using in `NODE` using the `==` operator.

---

**Edit** per new data set

```
indx <- as.logical(rowSums(with(d1, 
                  node == tolower(stri_split_regex(sentence, "[ :?.,]",
                  simplify = TRUE)))))

d1[indx, ]
#  node                  sentence
# 3 aids Hij zei dat hij aids had.
# 4 aids         Aids in het land?
```

---

**Edit #2** (trying to make it less "resource intensive")

```
myfunc <- function(x, y) any(x == y)
indx <- with(d1, mapply(myfunc, node, stri_split_regex(tolower(sentence), "[ :?.,]")))
d1[indx, ]
#  node                  sentence
# 3 aids Hij zei dat hij aids had.
# 4 aids         Aids in het land?
```

Comment: Didn't see your edit at first. This seems to work, nice. Could you explain the first part of `indx`? What does rowSums do? And `simplify`?

Comment: Applying this on a large set does seem quite resource intensive though (just saying for future readers).

Comment: `stri_split_regex` creates a matrix (thus the `simplify = TRUE` - so it won't be a list) and then I'm just using `rowSums` in order to sum matches per row. If the sum is bigger than `0`, `as.logical` will convert it to `TRUE`. This will give me a `TRUE/FALSE` index per row.

Comment: Ok, I gave it a thought and decided that probably `simplify = TRUE` makes this very resource intensive. See my second edit. Maybe this will be more efficient.

Comment: This seems faster indeed. Thanks. I'll do some further testing and then accept your answer or nico's.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
# Use grep to match \bNODE\b in SENTENCE row by row
matches <- mapply(grep, paste0("\\b", df$NODE, "\\b"), df$SENTENCE)
# Find rows with at least one match
to.keep <- sapply(matches, length)>=1
# Keep those
df[to.keep,]
```

Note that grep returns `logical(0)` if no match is found so I use `length` to test for matches. The `sapply` call will result in a vector containing the number of matches per word.

**EDIT**: following the editing of the question

you can use `ignore.case=T` to make the matches case insensitive.
I updated the regular expression to take into account sentence boundaries. There must be an easier way though...

```
matches <- mapply(grep, paste0("\\s", d1$node, "\\s|^", d1$node, 
           "|", d1$node, "$"), d1$sentence, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Comment: @Thomas hmmmm `sapply` does not return a logical vector in this case

Comment: @BillWoodger no reason, I just happened to write that..., >0 works as well

Comment: @Thomas ah, right, yes that will work, corrected it!

Comment: I am currently running this command on my data so I'll let you know what the result is. However, I do wonder: to make this capital insensitive, would I simply use `mapply(grep, (?i)paste0("\\b", df$NODE, "\\b"), df$SENTENCE)`?

Comment: See the edit to my main post, this isn't working as expected. However, using `\\s` instead of `\\b` works. Doesn't `-` imply a word boundary? The down-side of this is that it won't detect when the node is at the beginning or end of a sentence (because it then isn't preceded or followed by a spatial character).